# D365 Error when calling function from another JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am having an issue calling JS function from another JS file.

Main JS where the function is defined.

```
var Common = Common || {};
Common.BaseAction = Common.BaseAction || {};

Common.BaseAction.SetNotification = function (message, level, uniqueId)
{
Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification(message, level, uniqueId);
}

Common.BaseAction.clearNotification = function (uniqueId) {
Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification(uniqueId);
}
```

JS from where I am calling the function

```
var apItem = apItem || {};
apItem.BaseForm = apItem.BaseForm || {};

apItem.BaseForm.SetName = function ()
{
var bookName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ap_bookid").getValue()[0].name;
var condition = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ap_condition").getText();

if (bookName !== null && condition !== null) {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ap_name").setValue(bookName + " - " + condition);
}
}

apItem.BaseForm.CountOverDueBy = function() {
var rentedTill = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ap_rented_till").getValue();
var nowD = Date.now();

if (rentedTill !== null) {
    var overdueBy = parseInt((Date.now() - rentedTill) / 86400000);

    if (overdueBy > 0) {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ap_overdue_by").setValue(overdueBy);
        Common.BaseAction.SetNotification("Book is Overdue by " + overdueBy 
+ " Days.", "WARNING", "OverDueWarning");
    }
    else {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ap_overdue_by").setValue(null);
        Common.BaseAction.clearNotification("OverDueWarning");
    }
}
}
```

In the entity's form, I have added both above files with `common.js` being at the top and from the event handler I am calling function `apItem.BaseForm.CountOverDueBy`

Save + Published and Ctrl + F5 gives following error

```
ReferenceError: Common is not defined
    at Object.apItem.BaseForm.CountOverDueBy (https://<domain>/%7B636651014350000438%7D/WebResources/ap_ItemFormBase.js?ver=2091450722:24:13)
    at eval (eval at RunHandlerInternal (https://<domain>/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=2091450722:153:1), <anonymous>:1:17)
    at RunHandlerInternal (https://<domain>/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=2091450722:159:1)
    at RunHandlers (https://<domain>/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=2091450722:118:1)
    at OnScriptTagLoaded (https://<domain>/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=2091450722:233:1)
    at https://<domain>/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=2091450722:202:1
```

I have tried everything but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Can you add the common.js as dependency to second js file & see? This way you don’t need to register every file in every form.

Comment: Forgive me Arun, but how do I do that?

Comment: Go to js2 web resource, in dependency tab add common.js https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/jaredjohnson/2018/02/05/dynamics-365-v9-javascript-web-resource-dependencies

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you register the JS files in form, starting from `common.js` on top & then `ap_ItemFormBase.js` should work. But product team made few performance improvements around script files like lazy script loading/parallel script loading. This is little tricky & modern scripting is messy between different clients like UUI & web.

[Like explained in blog post](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/jaredjohnson/2018/02/05/dynamics-365-v9-javascript-web-resource-dependencies), if you set the pre-requisite js as dependency, it will load before you consume it in dependent files.

Open the `ap_ItemFormBase.js` web resource from solution (not from Form Properties), go to **Dependencies** tab & add the `common.js`. This will make sure file is ready before reference is used.